AutGen DotNet - Always creates an Inner Agent of AutoGen.OpenAI.GPTAgent
Playing about with AutoGen and Azure OpenAI.  I am going through the very simple example from here: https://microsoft.github.io/autogen-for-net/articles/Create-an-agent.html


Every time I post a message I get the following error: No Content.

Looking at the payload it is 100% not send the content with the request:

I just don't know why.
When debugging the construction of the assistant, it appears the inner Agent is always AutoGen.OpenAI.GPTAgent, I was expecting it to be Of AzureOpenAiAgent.
Any hints?
I was expect to have a inner agent to be AzureOpenAI.
I have tried using a different agent, but get the same result.

Anyone got any hints?
